# Lightning extension for x86_64 Thunderbird 3.1.10?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, thunderbird, lightning

I've installed the Thunderbird 3.1.10 package in latest Arch Linux x86_64. However, it seems that the Lightning calendar extension doesn't work in this 64-bit operating system with 64-bit Thunderbird (I get an error message saying so).

Where can I find and install a 64-bit compatible version of the Lightning extension? (it is not in the official Mozilla websites) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one works for me
http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/calendar/lightning/releases/1.0b2/contrib/linux-x86_64/

Comment: Using the same version here (also on arch x64), works perfectly.